# Python socket gethostbyname() returns only one IP address

Tags: python, sockets

I'm doing some simple experiments using Python socket, where I've a HOSTNAME which resolves with two IP addresses but when I use, 
 
 `socket.gethostbyname('demo.sample.com')` 
 
 I'm getting only one IP address. Why is it showing that way? Is there any other way I can get multiple IP addresses?

**EDIT - 1**

I got it guys, instead of `gethostbyname('demo.sample.com')` 
I tried `gethostbyname_ex('demo.sample.com')` 
 It gives the result as I expected.

Comment: Normally DNS resolves a single host to a single IP address. Why do you expect more than one?

Comment: This is just a wrapper around the C library `gethostbyname`, which gives you just one answer if any.  If you want to dig into DNS details, you need a DNS module such as `pydns` or [`dnspython`](http://www.dnspython.org/).

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara It is possible to assign multiple IP to a single hostname, I want to know what are the ip addresses assigned for the hostname I give, Simply to say, I just want the results of `nslookup` command in linux

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara if you are calling gethostbyname on a device that is on your LAN, your query doesn't make it to the DNS. Any of your devices can have multiple interfaces, each with their own IP. I have about 6 different interfaces/IPs on my laptop (some of them are VirtualBox adapters).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) it is visible that:

- gethostbyname returns only a single IPv4 address. And to cite:
   *See gethostbyname_ex() for a more complete interface.*
- gethostbyname_ex will return multiple IPv4 address, but check out the usage. And to cite:
   *gethostbyname_ex() does not support IPv6 name resolution, and getaddrinfo() should be used instead for IPv4/v6 dual stack support.*
- getaddrinfo will return all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but check out the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/521/socket.gethostbyname), which returns the internal network IP:

```py
import socket


def ip_addr(hostIP=None):
    if hostIP is None or hostIP == 'auto':
        hostIP = 'ip'

    if hostIP == 'dns':
        hostIP = socket.getfqdn()
    elif hostIP == 'ip':
        from socket import gaierror
        try:
            hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
        except gaierror:
            logger.warn('gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn()) failed... trying on hostname()')
            hostIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        if hostIP.startswith("127."):
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            # doesn't have to be reachable
            s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
            hostIP = s.getsockname()[0]
    return hostIP


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('%s' % ip_addr())
```